# Block code run from the inspect element in JS?

Tags: javascript, inspect-element

I have a javascript game that people have started hacking by changing the score variable from the console in the inspect element, is there a way to make it so that code from the inspect element console will not be run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use scoped variables, so the attacker can't access them from the console.

```js
const unscoped = "you can reach me from the console";
console.log(unscoped);

{
  const scoped = "you can NOT reach me from the console";
}
console.log(scoped);
```

Another option would be to wrap all of your code in an [Immediately Invoking Function Expression (IIFE)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

```js
"use strict";
(function game() {
  //code goes here
  for (var score = 0; score <= 5; score++) console.log("Score: ", score);
})();

console.log("Attacking attempt:");
console.log(score);
```

EDIT: that last one requires you to use strict mode (type `"use strict";` at the beginning of the file)

Comment: so this solution stores the variable in an unnamed object literal? how does that make it inaccessible to the console?

Comment: It uses scoping; basically, when you define variables locally (within `{ }` curly braces), they can only be accessed *within* that scope (so within those curlies). The console context is always the `window` object, so those variables will not be defined.

Comment: So no, it is not an unnamed object literal, it is a code block: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block

Answer (score -1):

i found this code it can be helpful:

```
<script>
/* To Disable Inspect Element */
$(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
});

$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which === 123){
       return false;
    }
});
</script>
```

refrence:

https://www.codingtag.com/how-to-disable-inspect-element

Comment: what does it do? how?